# nativescript-vue / Error in firebase.query: ReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: FIRDatabase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nativescript-vue

I have authenticated successfully in firebase with my app.
I have imported a user-collection and want to query this data.

My code in methods:

```
import firebase from "nativescript-plugin-firebase";
...

getData(){

                var onQueryEvent = function(result) {

                    if (!result.error) {
                        console.log("Event type: " + result.type);
                        console.log("Key: " + result.key);
                        console.log("Value: " + JSON.stringify(result.value)); // a JSON object
                        console.log("Children: " + JSON.stringify(result.children)); // an array, added in plugin v 8.0.0
                    }
                };

                    firebase.query(
                    onQueryEvent,
                    "/Users",
                    {

                        singleEvent: true

                    }
                );

            }   // get data
```

Data in firebase:
[image]

Now i get the error:
 **'Error in firebase.query: ReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: FIRDatabase'**

I have done all the suggestions from Eddy Verbruggen, but no chance, it's not working.

THX for help in advance.

**edit: This is the solution:**

```
import firestore from "nativescript-plugin-firebase/app/firestore";

const db = firebase.firestore;

  getData(){


                db.collection("Users").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                  });
             });
```

and the data:

> CONSOLE LOG file:///app/components/Home.vue:55:0: 'K100' ' => ' {
>   email: 'Andy.Zniston@mail.com', firstname: 'Zniston', name: 'Andy' }
>   CONSOLE LOG file:///app/components/Home.vue:55:0: 'K1000' ' => ' {
>   email: 'Armando.Zemario@mail.com', firstname: 'Zemario', name:
>   'Armando' }

Comment: Ralf, just getting back to this. So, you didn't have to call firebase.init()?

Comment: And you didn't have to add any async code to deal with network delays?

Comment: @Ed Jones, no only this code. There is almost no delay-time. It's very fast. But i will go to Amazon AWS DB's. Just trying....